# how to retrieve data from table using jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, mysql-workbench

I am Trying to retrieve data from questions table but this below code is not showing an output.

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>


<%  
Connection con = null;  
Statement st   = null;
ResultSet rs   = null;

try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/users","root", "1234");
String qry = "SELECT * FROM questions";
rs = st.executeQuery(qry);

while(rs.next()){
   out.println("Email :" + rs.getString(2) + "<br>");
   out.println("Title :" + rs.getString(3) + "<br>");
   out.println("Description :" + rs.getString(4) +"<br>");
}
}
catch(Exception ex){}
%>
```

[image: questions table screenshot]

[image: Screenshot of output]

Answer (score 0):

What is out.println?  that's not how you output using scriptlets.  it should look something like this:

```
        while(rs.next()){
           %>
           <%="Email :" + rs.getString(2) + "<br>"%>
           <%="Title :" + rs.getString(3) + "<br>"%>
           <%="Description :" + rs.getString(4) +"<br>"%>
           <%
        }
```

And most people would say to not use scriptlets to begin with.

If that doesn't fix the problem, you might have caught an exception.  Try and output the exception like this:

```
   catch(Exception ex){%><%=ex.toString()%><%}
```

It looks like you have a  java.lang.NullPointerException, so you have to figure out which object you are trying to use is null.  Looking at your code, it looks like you never initialize your `Statement st`.  Try adding in `st = con.createStatement()` after the line that says `con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/users","root", "1234");`

Comment: You might have an exception.  look at my edit to output the exception and let me know if you caught one.

Comment: yes , It is showing this exception  ->   java.lang.NullPointerException